# Word to describe someone who is a lover of bridges

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe someone who loves or enjoys bridges (look at, go over, or appreciate engineering).

Something similar to the way oenophile means someone who loves wine.

Comment: A *bridge-lover* is also probably a trophy-winner of the same.

Comment: If you want something that will be understood it's "bridge lover" or "bridge-ophile".

Comment: I personally would call that person a [Billington](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_art)!

Comment: @JimiOke it's definitely not that, I like them for rugged efficiency not art.  So I'm not too much a fan of the Golden Gate, but I think freeway overpasses are nice or even a downed tree in a jungle over a ravine or river.  Those are really aesthetic to me for some reason.

Comment: @Neil: Haha no worries. That was more tongue-in-cheek than anything. Just an opportunity to slot in that name :)

Comment: Oh ok jimioke :)

Comment: Bridge contractors? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge . Jes kiddin !!

Comment: @tchrist might not a *bridge lover* be someone who loves playing the card game?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, though context will probably disambiguate.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Indeed, and that was my thought regarding the trophy for duplicate bridge tournaments.

Comment: I thought tchrist was just kidding ;)  It wouldn't make sense to look at, go over, and enjoy the engineering of a card game.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word is ***pontist***.

> **1.** A historic bridge enthusiast who enjoys either lobbying for preservation and/or who enjoys visiting and photographing historic bridges.
>  **2.** Anyone who enjoys working with or visiting/photographing bridges of any kind.
>
> [[Urbandictionary]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pontist)

It also appears in one of the reviews of the book "Bridges of the World: Their Design and Construction" (By Charles S. Whitney):

> A book to delight the heart and eye of a **pontist** whether he be an admirer and lover of bridges or a designed or builder..." -*Saturday Review of Literature*

It is coined from Latin *pont-*, stem of *pons* "bridge". (See: [similar words](http://wordinfo.info/unit/1727/ip:12/il:P))

Another example from the book "Historic Iron and Steel Bridges in Maine, New Hampshire and Vermont" (By Glenn A. Knoblock):

> This is a book intended for anyone who has an interest in bridges, whether they are a **bridge enthusiast ( a "pontist")**, civil engineer, native New Englander or someone from outside the region.

Comment: There's even a blog called [The Happy Pontist](http://happypontist.blogspot.it/) written by a bridge designer.

Comment: I think this might be the word I'm looking for, but does it have to be for historic bridges?  What about those ones you go over on the freeway while driving?  There isn't a definition in a normal dictionary that I can locate :(  Only Urbandictionary so I don't think it counts.

Comment: @Neil: It appears that it covers all kind of activities that can indicate love of bridges. It covers loving them in general as well as photographing, visiting, designing, engineering etc.

Comment: @Neil: These kind of coined words are not always in big dictionaries but they are generally accepted in the domain that they are used. You are even lucky to find it on urbandictionary. I included supporting evidence from books about bridges. (and there are other books using it if you check Google Books)

Comment: Ermanen you did a really thorough and good job :)

Answer (score 6):

The Greek word for *bridge* is *γέφυρα,* so a lover of bridges would be a ***gephyrophile*** (or maybe *gefurophile*, depending on how the Greek is to be transliterated).

Comment: Gephyrophilia is the more classical transliteration. Indeed, the term is sometimes used to refer to an obsessive compulsion to cross bridges.

Comment: [Yes, I'm calling it Gephyrophilia.
It means love of bridges, more or less, a love of crossing them](http://www.thexbridge.com/geph001.html)

Comment: OED has only a few *gephyr-* entries, but that seems to be the preferred transliteration.

Comment: Oh, OK then ...